# How can I prevent a follower from participating in fights in RPG Maker?

Tags: rpg-maker

I'm developing a game with RPG Maker VX Ace. In this game, one of your followers is ghost-like demon that observes the player. I was going to have him appear during dialogues, but all of the playtesters were getting confused as he looks like the character the player interacts with.

I decided to make him a follower so it gets less confusing, but I don't think it would be interesting for him to participate in fights, as he would be too overpowered. I was able to prevent him from attacking, but not able to prevent him from *being attacked*.

How can I make this follow not participate in fighting at all?

Comment: On previous versions there was some scripts which allowed you to add followers but all would make them join the fights. I guess you can take a look on them to create your own scripts with the restrictions you've set.

Comment: I removed your question about standing on the diagonal because it's really a completely separate question you should ask; we generally prefer that you have one question per post here.

Comment: If the follower only follows and appears in dialoges, but has no effects on the game otherwise, you could remove them at the start of a fight and add them to the party again after the fight.

Answer (score 0):

Before every battle, have the game trigger a `Common Event` that removes him as a follower from the party. Using some more battle scripting within the `Database > Troops` menu can add him back as a follower when the battle is won. 
You can also have him be a follower just as a basic event that travels along with you, and therefore, cannot enter into battle alongside the party.